# Missing desired character in string with a Regex call

Tags: python-3.x, regex, dataframe

I'm missing a desired character from this string:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({Score:[1.20\n1\n99%\n6.75\nX\n-\n14\n2\n1%\n+72]})
```

Desired result:

```
1.20\n6.75\n14.00
```

Here is the regex I used:

```
.str.findall(r'(?m)^\d+\.\d+$').str.join("\n")
```

This regex is not capturing `\n14`; I want the result to be `\n14.00`. In other words the regex must handle the missing float point and inserting the `00` as appropriate. Meaning if this happens across any of the desired values in the list/string. So I'm stuck on finding a solution.

See the current regex result in code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df=pd.DataFrame({'Score: ['1.20\n1\n99%\n6.75\nX\n-\n14\n2\n1%\n+72']})

df = df['Score'].str.findall(r'(?m)^\d+\.\d+$').str.join("\n")
df
0       1.20\n6.75
Name: Score, dtype: object
```

Comment: Maybe you just want `r'(?m)^(?:\d+\.\d+|\d{2,})$'`? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZ8ekb/1). What are the rues here?

Comment: Note that `(?m)^(?:\d+\.\d+|\d+$(?=\n\d+$))$` also [seems](https://regex101.com/r/QZ8ekb/2) to work, but it follows a different logic. What is the logic you need?

Comment: Thanks. Will check the rues...learning my regret

Comment: A regexp can't add anything, all it can do is return parts of the input string. If you want to modify the result, you need to use `.str.replace()`

Comment: I want the regex to capture the value even if the float number is missing ie. when only the integer is in place. This may happen from time to time across the desired values. Sorry my explanation may lack the correct technical standard

Comment: @Barmar Will check on your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas:

1. You might want to match lines with only float values or with integers that contain at least two digits:

```py
r'(?m)^(?:\d+\.\d+|\d{2,})$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZ8ekb/1).

2. You may extract all lines that only contain float numbers and any amount of digits if the next line also only contains digits:

```py
(?m)^(?:\d+\.\d+|\d+$(?=\n\d+$))$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZ8ekb/2).

In Pandas, you can use

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'Score': ['1.20\n1\n99%\n6.75\nX\n-\n14\n2\n1%\n+72']})
df['ID']=df['Score'].str.findall(r'(?m)^(\d+\.\d+|\d{2,})$')
df['ID']=df['ID'].apply(lambda x: "\n".join(map(lambda a: f'{a:.2f}', map(float,x))))
>>> df['ID']
# => 0    1.20\n6.75\n14.00
#    Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hello. If you can check follow up question when you can. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65659338/11496486