# Is regex or replace method best to clean up list ? re Pandas environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

From the list below I'm able to remove the non-alphabet characters but fall short all the same. I want the Draw eliminated without affecting the desired outcome.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Teams': ['Lakefield United',
 '101002 Castle FC pk, +½ 1.81 o 3.05 o Un 2 1.92 o',
 '101003 Draw 3.00 o',
 'Boms',
 '101005 Riverside FC pk 2.11 o 2.86 o Un 2, 2½ 1.78 o',
 '101006 Draw 3.10 o',
 'Barmley',
 '101011 Colsely Lakers -1, -1½ 2.04 o 1.46 o Un 2½, 3 1.83 o',
 '101012 Draw 4.40 o',]})
```

**Desired Elements**: `'Lakefield United\nCastle FC','Boms\nRiverside FC','Barmley\nColsely Lakers'` etc.

Comment: Getting the first team is easy, simply pick every third element. However, the data with the opposing team's name is impossible to process blind, because the format is different for each one. Some have `pk` after the team name, one doesn't. Two have `,` after the element after the team name, one doesn't. Two team names have `FC` in them, one doesn't. See what I mean? You'll have to generate a preexisting list with all possible team names, then search for each of them until you get a match.

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you for the information. Will follow through.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, this requires constructing a termination list for determining when the second team's name ends.  Below is one way to do it.  You may need to add more items to your termination list, but there will be a limited number of them.  I have also converted the dataframe to a list for ease of manipulation.

```
lst = df.to_numpy().tolist() #convert dataframe to list
termination_list = [",", "p", "-"] #develop list of strings that would terminate the team name
termination_list += [str(n) for n in range(10)] #add number strings to termination_list

result = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i% 3 == 0: #string containing first team
        next_string = lst[i + 1][0] #string containing second team
        next_team = ""
        for j in range(6, len(next_string)):
            if next_string[j] in termination_list:
                break
            next_team += next_string[j] #construct next team name, letter by letter
        result.append((lst[i][0], next_team)) #append tuple of (first team, second team)
print(result)
```

Note that this code might cut short the name of any team that has "p" in it.  You can fix this by refining the termination list.

Comment: Thank you. I'll work through your solution.